# Rails: Sunspot and Will_Paginate Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, indexing, sunspot, will-paginate

I've hit a snag with my college project regarding the use of the Sunspot search gem and will_paginate. I've been using sunspot in my project index controller and it was working fine but when I added pagination to the same index it created a problem. I cant seem to have both the search and pagination at the same time.

This gives me the pagination (see below):

def index

```
@projects = Project.all
@projects = Project.paginate :per_page => 4, :page => params[:page]
respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @projects }
end
```

end

This gives me my search index (see below):

def index

```
@projects = Project.all
@search = Project.search do
  fulltext params[:search]
end
@projects = @search.results
respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @projects }
end
```

end

But when I add the pagination it doesn't work/display (see below):

def index

```
@projects = Project.paginate :per_page => 4, :page => params[:page]
@search = Project.search do
  fulltext params[:search]
end
@projects = @search.results
respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @projects }
end
```

end

The search still works but the pagination doesn't appear...
Any ideas how I get them both working together?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question here, never occured to me to add in IF and ELSE to separate the actions in the def index....

This works perfectly...

```
if params[:search]
@search = Project.search do
  fulltext params[:search]
end
  @projects = @search.results
else
@projects = Project.all
@projects = Project.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 4)
respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @projects }
end
```